# Do these two statements mean the same thing?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Will the following two statements do the exact same thing, including side effects like late binding?

```
Ilist<SomeClass> sessions = SomeFunction()
var tmp = from session in sessions
          select new ConnectedUsers()
              {
                  ID = session.SessionId,
                  Username = session.UserName,
                  HostName = session.ClientName,
                  IpAddress = session.ClientIPAddress.ToString()
              };
var tmp2 = sessions.Select((session) => new ConnectedUsers() 
        { 
            ID = session.SessionId, 
            Username = session.UserName, 
            HostName = session.ClientName, 
            IpAddress = session.ClientIPAddress.ToString() 
        });
```

EDIT:
and will similar statements allays be the same if I use the first syntax or the second syntax

Comment: You don't need parentheses around `session`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will transform the first method into the second one during the compilation process.

However, if you make a non-trivial query expression with a trivial `select` clause, the `Select` call will not be emitted.
Therefore, each of the following pairs of expresisons will compile identically:

```
from x in Enumerable.Range(0,1000) where x / 2 == x / 2.0 select x
Enumerable.Range(0,1000).Where(x => x / 2 == x / 2.0)  //No Select call
```

---

```
from x in Enumerable.Range(0,1000) select x
Enumerable.Range(0,1000).Select(x => x)
```

Comment: Are you sure that last one emits a Select? Seems kinda pointless, unless you (or the compiler) want to ensure you get a copy of the enumerable.

Comment: @leppie: Yes; I tried it.  The entire expression is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Compile it, and look at the generate code in IL or via Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Although you don't need the parenthesis after `ConnectedUsers`.

Comment: I see you also need some filler text :)

Comment: Somewhat subjective, but I'd say you should always put it anyway and be consistent with non-parameterless cases. ;)

Comment: @leppie While I hate the miniumum, I also don't like unnecessary code.